# Need to write a query for the below sub string between the dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

```
ROW_ID  STATUS      CREATED_DATE
123    PROCESSED    06/01/16 03:17:59 AM - 1-XHV8EV
123    INPROGRESS   06/01/16 03:18:59 AM - 1-XHV8EV
123    INPROGRESS   06/02/16 10:17:59 AM - 1-XHV8EV
123    INPROGRESS   06/02/16 10:18:59 AM - 1-XHV8EV
123    PROCESSED    06/02/16 11:17:59 AM - 1-XHV8EV
123    PROCESSED    06/02/16 11:17:59 AM - 1-XHV8EV
```

I want to retrieve all the records in between the dates from 06/01/16 03:1:59 AM to 06/02/16 11:17:59 AM

The output should be like this

Output :

```
ROW_ID  STATUS      CREATED_DATE
123     INPROGRESS  06/01/16 03:18:59 AM - 1-XHV8EV
123     INPROGRESS  06/02/16 10:17:59 AM - 1-XHV8EV
123     INPROGRESS  06/02/16 10:18:59 AM - 1-XHV8EV
```

I want to retrieve all the records in between the dates from 06/01/16 03:1:59 AM to 123    PROCESSED    06/02/16 11:17:59 AM

Comment: Things like this are why you shouldn't store dates as strings.

Comment: I also got the same doubt but the database was designed like that long back someone else in the company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ROW_ID, STATUS, CREATED_DATE ) AS
SELECT 123, 'PROCESSED',  '06/01/16 03:17:59 AM - 1-XHV8EV' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 'INPROGRESS', '06/01/16 03:18:59 AM - 1-XHV8EV' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 'INPROGRESS', '06/02/16 10:17:59 AM - 1-XHV8EV' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 'INPROGRESS', '06/02/16 10:18:59 AM - 1-XHV8EV' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 'PROCESSED',  '06/02/16 11:17:59 AM - 1-XHV8EV' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123, 'PROCESSED',  '06/02/16 11:17:59 AM - 1-XHV8EV' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TO_DATE( SUBSTR( created_date, 1, 20 ), 'MM/DD/YY HH12:MI:SS AM' )
       BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2016-06-01 03:18:59'
       AND     TIMESTAMP '2016-06-02 11:17:00';
```

**Output**:

```
    ROW_ID STATUS     CREATED_DATE                  
---------- ---------- -------------------------------
       123 INPROGRESS 06/01/16 03:18:59 AM - 1-XHV8EV 
       123 INPROGRESS 06/02/16 10:17:59 AM - 1-XHV8EV 
       123 INPROGRESS 06/02/16 10:18:59 AM - 1-XHV8EV
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that " - 1-XHV8EV" part of the data?  If so, you will have to do some fancy SQL statements to strip that out.

It would be something like

```
CAST (LEFT(CREATED_DATE,20) as DATE)
```

Which should give you a CASTed date to work with.  Then you can run that in a between

```
WHERE  CAST (LEFT(CREATED_DATE,20) as DATE) between someDate and someOtherDate
```

Comment: Are you sure this is an Oracle answer? `ORA-00904: "LEFT": invalid identifier` and `CAST( .. AS DATE )` will only work if the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter is the exact format mask needed to match the string - so this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Applying any function on the created_date column will stop any indexes on that column from getting used in your SQL. Please check if function based indexes could be applied for created_date column.
2. Also please ensure that you always get the date string populated in the exact format you are applying to extract the date out of created_date. Any change in that format would cause application to error out. Even if you fix such issues at code level, the function based index would become redundant.

All said and done, these fixes are temporary. A permanent fix for this issue is only with the table design. If that is a major effort, try devising a plan to break it down into multiple smaller tasks and progressively change the logically dependent objects to eventually get rid of this issue once and for all.

Good Luck.